# Bind enum into ViewModel using C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I have an enum class where it has few statuses. I want to bind my enum to the combobox and once the save button is click it should save into the database by using mvvm pattern. For now, i am able to populate the enum statuses into the combobox, but can i bind it to the view model? And how can i save into the database from the enum.

Here is the xaml code:

```
 xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:application.Enum"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Home" Height="450" Width="700">
 <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ProductionLineConfigViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enum:Status"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combobox_status" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5.8,41.8,43.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="combobox_status_SelectionChanged"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductionLineStatus}" SelectedValue="{Binding ProductionLineStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="ProductionLineStatus"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Content="Back" Margin="24.8,7,24.8,42.6" x:Name="btnBack" Click="btnBack_Click"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Content="Create" Margin="24.8,7,24.8,42.6" x:Name="btnCreate" Click="btnCreate_Click" Command="{Binding NewProductionLineConfigCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

And this is the error message I am getting now:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ProductionLineStatus' property not found on 'object' ''Status'
>   (HashCode=0)'. BindingExpression:Path=ProductionLineStatus;
>   DataItem='Status' (HashCode=0); target element is 'ComboBox'
>   (Name='combobox_status'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type
>   'Object')

Here is the viewmode:

```
public class ProductionLineConfigViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Database db = new Database();
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    MySqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    private ProductionLineConfig productionlineconfig;

    public ProductionLineConfig ProductionLineConfigs
    {
        get { return productionlineconfig; }
        set
        {
            productionlineconfig = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineConfigs");
        }
    }

    // TODO - List all productionline configs; Implement observablecollections
    public List<ProductionLineConfig> listAllProductionLineConfigs
    {
        get
        {
            var plc = new List<ProductionLineConfig>();
            string query;
            query = "select * from productionlineconfig";
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, db.GetConnection());
            da.Fill(dt);
            reader = db.QueryCommand(query);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                plc.Add(new ProductionLineConfig()
                {
                    ProductionLineId = Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString()),
                    ProductLineCode = reader[1].ToString(),
                    ProductionLineName = reader[2].ToString(),
                    ProductionLineStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(reader[3].ToString()),
                    ProductionLineCreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[4].ToString())

                });
            }


            reader.Close();

            return plc;
        }
    }

    // TODO - Create new productionline config;
    public void createNewProductionLineConfig()
    {
        string query;

        try
        {
            query = "Insert into productionlineconfig (PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE, PRODUCTION_LINE_NAME, PRODUCTION_LINE_STATUS) Values ('" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductLineCode + "' , '" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineName + "' , '" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineStatus + "')";

            db.QueryCommand(query);

            Console.WriteLine("User created successfully");
            production_line_config plcWindow = new production_line_config();
            plcWindow.Hide();
            npi_home npiWindow = new npi_home();
            npiWindow.Show();

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }



    public NewProductionLineConfigCommand newProductionLineConfigCommand { get; set; }
    public ProductionLineConfigViewModel()
    {
        ProductionLineConfigs = new ProductionLineConfig();
        newProductionLineConfigCommand = new NewProductionLineConfigCommand(this);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the model code:

```
public class ProductionLineConfig : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    public int ProductionLineId
    {
        get { return id; }

        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineId");
        }
    }

    private string linecode;

    public string ProductLineCode
    {
        get { return linecode; }
        set
        {
            linecode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductLineCode");
        }
    }

    private string linename;

    public string ProductionLineName
    {
        get { return linename; }
        set
        {
            linename = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineName");
        }
    }


    private bool status;

    public bool ProductionLineStatus
    {
        get { return status; }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineStatus");
        }
    }

    private DateTime createddate;

    public DateTime ProductionLineCreatedDate
    {
        get { return createddate; }
        set
        {
            createddate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineCreatedDate");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add your ViewModel classes ?

Comment: @Alexus the production viewmodel class is not implemented for the status.

Comment: So where is the ProductionLineStatus property?

Comment: @Clemens I am sorry I am kinda beginner in mvvm. I implemented the property in my model class

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to set the ProductionLineConfigs property by selecting via its ProductionLineStatus, you can't bind ItemsSource to enum values. It should instead be bound to a collection of ProductionLineConfig objects.

Answer (score 0):

This helped to solve my problem

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox_status" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5.8,41.8,43.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="combobox_status_SelectionChanged"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineStatus, Converter={StaticResource statusToBooleanConverter}}" />
```